# How to position an image in the bottom right corner of a frame?

Tags: html, css

On the [this page (Roman Umismatics)](http://romanumismatics.com/auction/), I would like to position the yellow '`bid`' button at the bottom right of the individual frames.

#### Current code

`<p><a href="<?= $product->page_url() ?>"><img border="0" alt="Bid" src="/themes/roma/resources/img/bid.png" style="margin:0" /></a></p>`

What code do I need to change to do achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Add Class for the paragraph and float that paragraph to the right.

That will work.

```
<p class="alignright">

.alignright { float: right; }
```

Answer (score 2):

make the container element

```
.breakl

position: relative;
```

and make the bid button

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add 'float:right;' to the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
p{
   float:right:
   margin-top:10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

your html is:

```
<p><a href="/auction/lot/0003" class="actionBtn"><img border="0" alt="Bid" src="/themes/roma/resources/img/bid.png" style="margin:0;"></a></p>
```

CSS:

```
.actionBtn{float:right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will help:

**http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/**

When you set a parent to position: relative, you may then use absolute positioning on children, in relation to that container.

```
<div class="parent">
 <a class ="child" href="<?= $product->page_url() ?>"><img border="0" alt="Bid" src="/themes/roma/resources/img/bid.png" style="margin:0" /></a>
</div>
```

In your CSS:

```
.parent { position:relative; }
.child { display:inline-block; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; }
```